# find all call to a function in matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, dependencies

Say you modified a function, changed how many parameter it accepts as input  and how many it outputs; you've also modified its name for good measure.

Now you want to go and change all the calls to this function, because now the structure of the data is different, so every single call to this function will result in an error; how can you find a list of all the places where this function is called? This is sort of the inverse of depfun, which given a function it lists all the dependencies on file and other functions; I want a list of all the functions which depend on the function I input.

I looked into profile but the project is big and there isn't a unique entry point that touches each and every file, so it doesn't satisfy me

Thank in advance!

Comment: So you really wanna find it at runtime? Or wouldn't it be enough to search & replace using an editor like Notepad++ in all source-files?

Comment: Or write a function which is named like your original functions name and just call dbstack within it, so you'll get the complete callstack to see where it was called from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the semi-documented function [`getcallinfo`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/function-definition-meta-info/#getcallinfo).

### Simple example

Say you want to see in which lines the function `spiral` calls the function `ceil`:

```
h = getcallinfo('spiral.m');
h.calls.fcnCalls.lines(strcmp(h.calls.fcnCalls.names,'ceil'))
```

gives

```
ans =
     9    10
```

### General case

Since you want to do that for a whole project, you could **loop over all M-files in the folder**. Also, `getcallinfo` apparently returns an **array of structs**, where each element of the array refers to a different type of call: from the main function in the file, from subfunctions in that file, etc. So you need to loop over that too. (This didn't happen in the example above because `spiral` doesn't have any subfunctions.)

So you could proceed along these lines:

```
fn = 'disp'; % function you want track down
pp = 'path\to\folder'; % project path
d = dir([pp filesep '*.m']); % list M-files in folder. Not recursive
for k = 1:numel(d);
   file = d(k).name;
   h = getcallinfo(file);
   for n = 1:numel(h) % distinguish calls from subfunctions etc
      name = h(n).functionPrefix;
      lines = h(n).calls.fcnCalls.lines(strcmp(h(n).calls.fcnCalls.names, fn));
      if lines
         disp(['Function ' fn ' is called by function ' name ' at lines ' num2str(lines)])
      end
   end
end
```

Here's a sample output from a project of mine:

```
Function disp is called by function matl> at lines 190  198  199  232  257  269  280
Function disp is called by function matl_compile> at lines 32
Function disp is called by function matl_disp> at lines 77  79  81  83
Function disp is called by function matl_help> at lines 10  57  67  69  71  72  74  77
```

I have checked some of the lines and the results are correct. (You can check yourself [here](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL)).

Answer (score 0):

How about using the builtin Matlab dependency analysis?

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html?searchHighlight=identify%20program%20dependencies

It can show parents of functions within the same folder, but sadly cannot show dependencies from other folders.  If this is a problem, then you might want to look for all of the children functions from the parent folder, and work forward to see where your .m file is being referenced from.

To run a report, right click on a blank area in the "Current Folder" pane, and under Reports you'll find the Dependency Report.

(Of course, if you had Linux/Cygwin, then you could use find and grep:

```
find . -name "*.m" -exec grep -l "function" {} \;
```

where function is your .m file you have changed)

Answer (score 0):

There may be no need to change all calls to the function, you can just redefine old function to call modified function. For example modified function only takes a , c parameters of original function:

```
function [result1, result2] = old_fcn (a,b,c,d)
 [result1, result2] = modified_fcn(a(1:2), c');
end
```